# KOMA: format (sub) section number different that title

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I want my subsection heading to have an italic title but an upright number:

1.2.3 *My Title*

How can I reach this in `KOMA`? I only got the whole title in italics:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Or do I need `titlesec`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\itshape}

\newcommand\subsectionnumberfont{\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{\csname#1numberfont\endcsname#3\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

With newer versions of scrbook you do it like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\upshape \thesubsection\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution seems not to work anymore (KOMA-Script 3.19a). Is there an other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I tried to achieve something similar with `\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[40pt][r]{\\upshape\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}}` but it seems pretty wrong because of the fixed length of 40pt -- isn't there a more elegent way?

Comment: @harryhaller I edited the answer. But I have no idea why you introduced the makebox.